# "Extra W" sound in words

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, diphthongs, fast-speech-rules, semivowels

I've wonder that in some sentences, or words, even though phonetically you don't have a 'W' sound, you can still hear some type of extra w' sound. So for example.

The phrase: "Do it". /du ɪt/ will sound more like /du wɪt/

same with the verb= "doing" ˈduɪŋ becomes /ˈduwɪŋ/. Am I crazy?

Hope you can help me!

Comment: When I was coaching accent we called it liaison.

Comment: It's known as an Elmer Fudd accent.  (That's a joke, son.  A joke!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a so-called “linking semivowel”. It’s typically not perceived as being as strong a sound as “original” syllable-initial /w/, so some linguists don’t like to transcribe it (see this [blog post by the phonetician John Wells](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/08/linking-semivowels.html?m=1)).

The difference could be compared to the more drastic difference between the pronunciation of /p/ in “keep it” vs. “key pit”; the general principle is that consonants that come at the start of a word, or at the start of a stressed syllable at the word level, are “stronger” than other consonants.

“Linking semivowels” occur after “tense” high vowels or diphthongs ending in a high element; linking “w” occurs after vowels/diphthongs ending in a high back component and linking “j” occurs after vowels/diphthongs ending in a high front component.

Sometimes “linking semivowels” are written with superscript letters, although this is not consistent with the official IPA usage of superscript letters.

Comment: You truly are an expert in linguistics, aren't you? Thanks for the reply! :). You're always there to help!

Comment: I think a contributing factor may be that many dialects pronounce the GOOSE vowel as a falling diphthong such as [ʉu̯] to begin with.

Comment: @MarkBeadles The same thing happens, mutatis mutandis, with *say it* [ˈsejɪt] and *higher* [ˈhajəɹ] and *co-wed* [ˈkʰowɛd], but whether those respectively differ from *sate, hire, coed* will depend in each case on the speaker and utterance. The pivotal ambisyllabic glide simultaneously acts **both** as a semi-vowel to create a falling diphthong on the first syllable **and also** as a semi-consonant to create a rising diphthong on the second syllable. It’s not really possible to say that the glide belongs to either syllable to the exclusion of the other; it does double duty here.

Comment: I've heard it'll also depend on how fast they're speaking. If they're speaking really fast, it's possible they'll add that extra "w" sound, or that extra "y" sound. So, yea, I do have heard some speakers saying "I'll do anything" with a W, sometimes not, guess you're right about the speaker. Though, phrases like "DO IT" have it all the time, it's weird.

Comment: @CarlosFernandez That’s because the only way to say *do it* **without** a glide between the two is to introduce a glottal stop between the two words so that the glottis isn’t making any sound connecting the two and you can move to the second without letting the rounding leak through. This is quite unnatural in ordinary speech, coming off like two different sentences with a full stop between them: *“Do. It.”* That’s because /u/ is always a rounded sound in English. But compare English *No ace* with Spanish *No es*; only the English one has all that much of an extra /w/ sound; Spanish doesn’t.

Comment: I also have another doubt. The word "TO" can most of the time be reduced to just the the T an the schwa sound. how about the sentence. "I'm going to a party". "Into it", Will you pronounce it as : "əm ˈgoʊɪŋ tə wə ˈpɑrti 
ˈɪntə ɪt Or as: 
əm ˈgoʊɪŋ tu wə ˈpɑrti 
ˈɪntu wɪt

Comment: @CarlosFernandez Probably just /twə/ with one syllable, the first vowel being lost in rapid, connected speech as schwas so often are. The real trick is training your ear to hear the subtle /w/ there that makes that subtly not  the same as ***going to party*** /ˈgowəndəˈpɑrti/ as a verb without the article *a* for a noun, and from there often enough further collapsing to /ˈgʊnəˈpɑrti/, which has the vowel of PUT or GOOD in the first syllable now thanks to all the mashing together.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! YES, It makes sense with the 'U' sound having the extra 'W' sound. It defenietly sounds weird not adding that extra 'W' when the word before is the 'U' as in BOO vowel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZuI6yv5mkQ if you listen here at 1:15, you can see that when he says "through it" You can defenitely hear that extra 'W' sound, which I guess is made for linking purpose, to make the sentence sound more connected!

Comment: However, I must say that about words with the 'ou, au' diphthong, even if you don't make the extra 'W' sound, for some reason it still sounds pretty fine, I'm guessing its because due to the fact that in a diphthong the vowel as in 'book' has more rounded lips. but I will still make that extra 'W' just in case.

Comment: If you include intrusive r as a linking semivowel (which it kind of is, by definition), then they also occur, though rarely, after non-tense or non-high vowels: _spa is_ [ˡspɑːɹɪz], _tikka is_ [ˡtʰɪkʰəɹɪz], etc.

Comment: @CarlosFernandez Generally speaking, _to_ is not reduced to [tə] when it immediately precedes another reduced vowel, so _to a_ is most commonly [tʊʷə], which can then be further reduced in rapid speech. For example, “I’m going to a party” will often be reduced to just [ɑm ˡgoʷn̩ʊə̯ ˡpʰɑ˞ːɽi] in broadcast AmE.

Comment: "keep it" uses a schwa in fast speech: /'kiːpət/. "key pit" uses a stressed vowel: /kiː'pɪt/. Using a stressed vowel in "keep it" causes a break between "keep" and "it": /'kiːp.ɪt/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite able to notice the sounds you mention as a 'w', except, at some level, all a 'w' is is a fast transition to or from an /u/ vowel. If you say the word "wow" very slowly and drawn out, you'll see it starts with a vowel sound, and it's the transitions between the vowels that form the 'w's.